# how would you form dict from the the following file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a large file in the following format:

```
--
0058 name_1 0BA7 VOL 512.0 2018-04-07/12:00
0058 name_1 0BAF VOL 64.0 2018-04-07/12:00
0058 name_2 0C93 VOL 808.0 2018-04-07/12:00
0058 name_2 0CFF VOL 307.1 2018-04-07/12:00
0058 name_3 0F4F VOL 16.2 2018-04-07/12:00
0058 name_3 0F51 VOL 16.0 2018-04-07/12:00
0058 name_3 0F53 VOL 16.2 2018-04-07/12:00
--
```

What would be the best and optimised way to form dict with key from 2nd column so I can get following:

```
key: name_1 -> [ 0BA7,0BA7], [512.0,64.0]
key: name_2 -> [ 0C93,0CFF], [512.0,64.0] 
key: name_3 -> [ 0F4F,0F51,0F53], [16.2,16.0,16.0]
```

or  even

```
key: name_1 -> [ key[0BA7]->512.0, key[0BA7]->64.0]
... 
key: name_3 -> [ key[0F4F]->16.2, key[0F51]->16.0, key[0F53]->16.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way to do it, accounting for both of your possible output formats:

```
with read(my_file.txt, 'r') as infile:  # open the file
    lines = [i.split() for i in infile.readlines()[1:-1]]  # use list comprehension to put lines from the file in a more useful format
    # each line now looks like
    # [0058, name_1, 0BA7, VOL, 512.0, 2018-04-07/12:00]
    #  0     1       2     3    4      5
    my_dict = {}
    for line in lines:
        # version 1 of your intended output
        if not line[1] in my_dict:
            my_dict[line[1]] = ([line[2]], [line[4]])  # initialize as a new tuple
        else:
            my_dict[line[1]][0].append(line[2])  # already initialized, so we
            my_dict[line[1]][1].append(line[4])  #    add on to the end of what's there
        # version 2 of your intended output
        if not line[1] in my_dict:
            my_dict[line[1]] = {line[2]: line[4]}  # initialize as a new dict
        else:
            my_dict[line[1]][line[2]] = line[4]  # add a key to existing dict
return my_dict
```

I don't think it's possible to do this with a dict comprehension, since the keys build off each other dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If every line follows your sample, the easiest way is to split your line by space. As for reading your file I'd choose readline method, as to read one line at a time is better for a big file.

```
d = {}
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    _, key, val1, _, val2, _ = line.split()
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = {}
    d[key][val1] = val2
print(d)
```